# Implement TFlearn imdb lstm example by tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, lstm, sentiment-analysis, imdb

I'm implementing tflearn's lstm imdb [example](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/nlp/lstm.py) by tensorflow.

I used the same dataset, architecture and hyper-parameters (embedding size, max length of sentence and so on) as tflearn model do, but my model's performance is poor than the tflearn example(after 10 epochs, my model got about 52% accuracy while the example got near 80% ).

I'd appreciated it a lot if you can give me some advice to achieve the appropriate performance of the example.

Below is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tflearn.data_utils import to_categorical, pad_sequences
from tflearn.datasets import imdb
from tensorflow.contrib.rnn import BasicLSTMCell
import time



n_class = 2
n_words = 10000
EMBEDDING_SIZE = 128
HIDDEN_SIZE = 128
MAX_LENGTH = 100
lr = 1e-3

epoch = 10
TRAIN_SIZE = 22500
validation_size = 2500
batch_size = 128
KP = 0.8

# IMDB Dataset loading
train, test, _ = imdb.load_data(path='imdb.pkl', n_words=n_words,
                                valid_portion=0.1, sort_by_len=False)
trainX, trainY = train
validationX, validationY = test
testX, testY = _


# Data preprocessing
# Sequence padding
trainX = pad_sequences(trainX, maxlen=MAX_LENGTH, value=0.)
validationX = pad_sequences(validationX, maxlen=MAX_LENGTH, value=0.)
testX = pad_sequences(testX, maxlen=MAX_LENGTH, value=0.)

# Converting labels to binary vectors
trainY = to_categorical(trainY, n_class)
validationY = to_categorical(validationY, n_class)
testY = to_categorical(testY, n_class)

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    # input
    text = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, MAX_LENGTH])
    labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_class])
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

    embeddings_var = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_words, EMBEDDING_SIZE]), trainable=True)
    text_embedded = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings_var, text)

    print(text_embedded.shape)  # [batch_size, length, embedding_size]
    word_list = tf.unstack(text_embedded, axis=1)

    cell = BasicLSTMCell(HIDDEN_SIZE)
    dropout_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell, input_keep_prob=keep_prob, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)
    outputs, encoding = tf.nn.static_rnn(dropout_cell, word_list, dtype=tf.float32)

    logits = tf.layers.dense(outputs[-1], n_class, activation=None)

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(loss)

    prediction = tf.argmax(logits, 1)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(prediction, tf.argmax(labels, 1)), tf.float32))


train_steps = epoch * TRAIN_SIZE // batch_size + 1
print("Train steps: ", train_steps)


with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print("Initialized!")
    s = time.time()
    offset = 0

    for step in range(train_steps):
        offset = (offset * step) % (TRAIN_SIZE - batch_size)
        batch_text = trainX[offset: offset + batch_size, :]
        batch_label = trainY[offset: offset + batch_size, :]
        fd = {text: batch_text, labels: batch_label, keep_prob: KP}
        _, l, acc = sess.run([optimizer, loss, accuracy], feed_dict=fd)

        if step % 100 == 0:
            print("Step: %d  loss: %f  accuracy: %f" % (step, l, acc))

        if step % 500 == 0:
            v_l, v_acc = sess.run([loss, accuracy], feed_dict={
                text: validationX,
                labels: validationY,
                keep_prob: 1.0
            })
            print("------------------------------------------------")
            print("Validation:  step: %d  loss: %f  accuracy: %f" % (step, v_l, v_acc))
            print("------------------------------------------------")
    print("Training finished, time consumed:", time.time() - s, " s")
    print("Test accuracy: %f" % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
        text: testX,
        labels: testY,
        keep_prob: 1.0
    }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I made a stupid mistake!
The loss :

> loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels))

are supposed to be

> loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels))

then, the accuracy is like the tflearn example